# Geometry question on triangles

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle and let BB1, CC1 be respectively the bisectors of ∠B, ∠C with B1 on AC and C1 on AB. Let E, F be the feet of perpendiculars drawn from A onto BB1, CC1 respectively. Suppose D is the point at which the incircle of ABC touches AB. How can I prove that AD = EF.

Comment: They don't look equal on my drawing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $M$, $N$ be the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. Since $\angle AEB=90^\circ$, $NE=BN=\dfrac{AB}2$. Thus $\triangle BNE$ is isosceles at $N$, or $$\angle NEB=\angle NBE=\angle EBC,$$
where the second equality due to $BE$ being the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$. So $NE\parallel BC$. Since $MN\parallel BC$, we have that $E$ lies on (the line) $MN$.

Similarly $F$ lies on (the line) $MN$.

It follows that if $R$ is the intersection of $AD$ and $MN$, then $R$ is the midpoint of $AD$. So
$$NR=\frac{BD}{2}=\frac{AB+BC-AC}4.$$
It then follows that
$$RE=NE-NR=\frac{AB}2-\frac{AB+BC-AC}4=\frac{AB+AC-BC}4.$$
Similarly, we see that
$$RF=\frac{AB+AC-BC}4.$$
So $AD$ and $EF$ intersect at their common midpoint $R$.